# Reauthenticate as different user after logout using Ionic and Firebase

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, inappbrowser, firebase-authentication

I followed the firebase tutorial instructions from [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ionic/guide.html#section-user-authentication)

Then I added a logout button with this code in index.html

```
<div class="card" ng-show="authData" ng-click="logout()">
  <div class="item item-text-wrap">
    Hello {{authData.provider.displayName}}! Log Out
  </div>
</div>
```

Corresponding code in controller

```
$scope.logout = function(){
Auth.$unauth();
$scope.authData = null;
window.localStorage.removeItem("firebase:host:my-url.firebaseio.com");};
```

I can logout Ok.  But, later when I hit login button again it does not ask for Facebook credentials again.   So, I assume the credentials are stored somewhere and reused. So, I need to clear it - the window.localStorage is not the right one to clear.

The example uses the ngCordova plugin, inAppBrowser.  So it is stored in that perhaps.

Can someone tell me what I need to do be able to re-authenticate with a new prompt for credentials.  I see others struggled before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428441/firebase-unauth-with-google-doesnt-allow-change-of-user) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880102/firebase-facebook-and-twitter-re-authenticating), but the answers were not helpful.   Thanks.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. Calling `$unauth()` ends the Firebase Authentication session, but does not end the session of the underlying OAuth provider. If you want that, you'll have to find a way to explicitly terminate it in your code. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-angular/$24unauth$20does$20not$20kill$20oAuth$20Session/firebase-angular/yt8kzTEhLY8/LvNOZPZHjCMJ

Comment: @Frank - The link is not working.  Can you tell how to explicitly terminate it in Ionic.  That is the essence of my question.

Comment: Sorry for the broken link, this one should work: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-angular/yt8kzTEhLY8